# Проблема с const: требуется константное выражение

Tags: c, visual-studio

Я использую VS 2010 Express, настроил ее для работы с языком С.
Для примера простейшая программа. Я объявляю массив типа `char`. Хочу его размер задать через `const`. Но VS это объявление не видит. В чем может быть проблема? Вот пример:

```
const int SIZE = 26;
char alphabet[SIZE];
```

Пишет в ошибку, что требуется константное выражение.

Answer (score 3):

на чистых сях делай так

```
#define SIZE 26
```

P.S. Изначально в сях не было const и inline, но вообще то потом (после срр) было добавлено (а так же объявление переменных в for и комментарии в стиле плюсов). Почему у тебя не кушает их - хто знает
P.P.S. Попробовал на VC на сях. Да, const кушает саму по себе, но в размерах массива не принимает. Да, #define лучшее лекарство.

Comment: Не люблю я макросы. И тех, кто ими злоупотребляет -- тоже недолюбливаю. Есть же enum -- `enum {SIZE=26};` А при употреблении макросов возможны довольно труднообнаруживаемые ошибки.

Comment: Именно из-за ошибок стараюсь макросы избегать. Жаль, непонятно почему в размерах массива не кушает, ну ладно, буду юзать enum. Всем спасибо

Comment: Постарайтесь избегать творений имени Б.Гейтса.

Comment: @avp Это Вы об чём? или об ком? МS VC? Так он не причём.

Comment: В самом деле ? А у меня все аббревиатуры MS ассоциируются с этим лицом.

Comment: Вообще то я хотел сказать, что MS VC к данной проблеме отношения не имеет. А какое отношение имеет У.Гейтс к MS VC -- вопрос сложный, я этого не знаю. Сам БГ в молодости писал интерпретатор бейсика, а дальше -- вряд ли. Не до программизма было. Всё же БГ -- гениальный бизнесмен. (С чувством юмора. Была история как парни из Киева в середине 90х обменялись с ним свопами по e-mail).

Comment: в плюсплюсах чрезмерное использование предпроцессоров возможно и зло, но речь здесь идет о чистых сях, где дифайны вполне согласуются с идеалогией языка и изначально используется в кодах в качестве константы чуть менее чем полностью, енум же - изначально перечисление и скорее должно использоваться как тип с ограниченным набором значением, и использовать как константу только потому что есть такая догма, что "макросы это плохо" сказанная когда-то авторитетом с мировым именем, это, ИМХО, и есть настоящий изврат :)

Comment: Я не знаю, какой авторитет с мировым именем это сказал, это его проблемы. Мне приходилось самому наступать на эти грабли, так что из двух инструментов -- один внутри языка, другой -- вне, я выбираю первый. Да, enum -- перечисление, с определением констант внутри этого перечисления. В pascal'е эти константы имеют свой тип для каждого перечисления, в C, как и полагается языку низкого уровня -- все целые. Засилье define'ов в библиотеках -- наследие k&r C, где перечислений просто не было.

Answer (score 1):

Неплохо бы написать, **что за ошибка** у Вас.

Посмотрел у себя

```
#include <stdio.h>                                          
#include <stdlib.h>                                         
#include <string.h>
#include <windows.h>

#ifndef INTDEF
  const int SIZE = 26;
  char aa[SIZE];
#endif

main ()
{
#ifdef INTDEF
  const int SIZE = 26;
  char aa[SIZE];
#endif
  aa[1] = 'z';
}

c:/Documents and Settings/avp/src/hashcode $ gcc  t.c
t.c:7: error: 'SIZE' redeclared as different kind of symbol
c:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.5/../../../../include/windef.h:328: error: previous declaration of 'SIZE' was here
t.c:8: error: variable-size type declared outside of any function
c:/Documents and Settings/avp/src/hashcode $ gcc  -DINTDEF t.c
c:/Documents and Settings/avp/src/hashcode $
```

Ругань очевидна.

Comment: На лине gcc 4.6 без проблем. И на более ранних версиях ничего такого не замечал.

Comment: gcc 4.4.3 с локальным массивом -- всё ok, статический -- см. выше.

Comment: gcc ..  -ansi -pedantic : с const выдает ошибку, с перечислением все в порядке

Comment: Именно так

Answer (score 0):

Поддерживаю alexlz. Данный приём называется "трюк с перечислением" и обсуждается в книге «Эффективное использование C++. 55 верных способов улучшить структуру и код ваших программ», Правило 2: Предпочитайте const, enum и inline использованию #define.

Answer (score 0):

Это получается, что данный компилятор поддерживает только чистый С90 ? Может, есть какие-то настройки, которые включают поддержку более поздних форматов? Если нет, то берите другой компилятор, например, gcc.

Comment: С99 студия начала поддерживать с 2013, если я ничего не путаю.